# macOS Sierra lapack and blas

Tags: python, macos, scipy, lapack, blas

I am new to this stuff and have been looking for resource on how to get `Numpy` and `Scipy with`BLAS`as well as`LAPACK` on macOS. However, I fail to find one up-to-date tutorial on how to do that. I've also looked into [Scipy's page](https://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/macosx.html) but they are for 10.7 and 10.8

Any suggestions or pointers? Thank you!

Comment: Which BLAS are you aiming for? I would suggest to use MKL since mac usually uses Intel CPUs. The easiest way to achieve that would be to just use Anacona, it has a prebuilt numpy+mkl and scipy+mkl as default implementations. If you want to compile it yourself I would suggest OpenBLAS. Compile it from git, clone numpy and scipy, search for the OpenBLAS part in site.cfg.example and remove the commenting, rename it to site.cfg and just `pip install .`